# C++ generate new EC_KEY using OpenSSL 1.1.1n

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm very new to this OpenSSL stuff and trying to learn my way through it. I want to generate an ec key but its keep failing to generate. I'm currently using OpenSSL 1.1.1n and here's a snippet based on understaning of EC_Key through documentation and from other people's example online:

```
EC_KEY* key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
if (!key)
{
    ERROR
}

EC_GROUP* ecgroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
if (ecgroup)
{
    printf("ECGROUP IS NOT NULL!\n");
    if (EC_KEY_set_group(key, ecgroup) != 1)
    {
        ERROR
    }
}

if (EC_KEY_generate_key(key) != 1) //<-- fails at this function
{
    ERROR
}
```

Maybe this piece of code is from an older version of OpenSSL but I don't see that function being mentioned in a change log. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Thanks for Jakob's answer I was able to get some more information about the failure by using `ERR_get_error()` function. The error I see now is
`error:2406C06E:random number generator:RAND_DRBG_instantiate:error retrieving entropy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself in case someone is having this same issue.

I was able to get around this problem by building OpenSSl with `no-shared` flag. I'm not sure how that is affecting the lib in getting an entropy but that's the parameter that made the `EC_KEY_generate_key()` work.

Here's my working configuration command:
`perl Configure no-shared VC-WIN32`

Comment: Glad you got it working. This is a build on Windows I assume? Maybe some shared library dependencies could not be resolved correctly by the build system.

Comment: Yup, this is a build on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EC_KEY_generate_key.html) states:

> `EC_KEY_generate_key()` generates a new public and private key for the
> supplied eckey object. eckey must have an `EC_GROUP` object associated
> with it before calling this function. [...]

Did you associate an `EC_GROUP` with the key before calling the function? There is a function called `EC_KEY_set_group()` which can be used to add a group object. Such an object can be created with the [`EC_GROUP_new()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EC_GROUP_new.html).

By the way is there a reason, why you are still using OpenSSL 1.1.1. I would recommend using the latest version of the library OpenSSL 3.0. Even if you only want to learn stuff, it is probably more useful, if you immediately learn the newer version.

**Edit**
I do not know, what is behind your `ERROR` macro, but it might be a good idea to learn the OpenSSL error handling system. There are functions like [ERR_print_errors()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ERR_print_errors.html) that maybe could have given you a hint about what was going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jakob! I edited my question because I was able to find the specific reason for failure by using `ERR_print_errors()`. As for not using OpenSSL 3.0, I basically took over someone else's project and he insisted that I use the OpenSSL version that came with the project and its currently 1.1.1n :)

Comment: Also, I'm now setting the group but still getting the same error. It would be nice if there were some examples somewhere to see how those functions can be called.

Comment: @M.AtherKhan Unfortunately I am not an expert for OpenSSL. Maybe you can find some solution [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5787). Did you built OpenSSL from source or did you install a precompiled binary distribution?

Comment: Hey Jakob, I was able to get it working, check out my answer. Still, thanks for the help!! really appreciate it!